# Weird error in C program

Tags: c

This error comes only when im working in a C file (not CPP)

I came across a very weird error while working on some opengl sample, I narrowed it down to below code, which produces the same error I'm getting, type not found

```
#include "stdlib.h"
void Initialize(int, char*[]);

void main()
{
}

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 10; i>0;i--)
    {
        int j=0;
        j = j+2;
        int GlewInitResult2;
    }
}
```

I used visual studio 2008, OS: windows xp

cant understand why this is happening? is this a compiler bug?

(btw, it compiles fine if i save the file as a .CPP file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declarations after statements. In newer versions of C (like C99), you can have this but in older versions you cannot. Microsoft's C compiler is old. In C++ it's OK, which is why it builds.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft compilers only support C89 so declarations and code cannot be mixed. This is permitted in C++. When the source file has a `.c` extension it is treated as C source, when it has `.cpp` it is treated as C++.

To correct for C put all variable declarations at beginning of the scope in which they are to be used.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know Visual studio 2008 is not completely c99 compliant.

In standards before `c99` you have to declare your variables in the beginning of the program. But in `c99` declaration of variables can be done anywhere in the function.

Also in c++ there is no such restriction. In Windows when you create a file with extension `.cpp` it is treated as a c++ file. Hence the same program works when compiled as cpp.

Solutions:

1. Declare your variables right in the beginning of the function. Which
   is a good practice as well!
2. Change your compiler ! (Look at [**this**](http://codepad.org/obDhdySQ). No compiler error !)